# How to invoque different operations by reusing a single API function?

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement, api-design

My API function `execute_api()` shall perform specific operations for:

- method name : view / create / update / delete / update_all / delete_all
- method type : get / post

I want my code to reuse the same logic in `execute_api()` but tailor the execution to implement any operations I have listed above. Here a quick code snippet:

```
    void execute_api()
    {
        void fill_request_vo( Request& req); // Request is a .oml file
        void calculate_url(Request& req); // calculate the url for the server to hit depending upon the operation selected
        void calculate_header(Request& req); // calculate header for the server to hit depending upon the operation selected

        // execute the services based on some conditions 
        // ResponseVO will be filled in case of success scenerio

        void parse_response(Response& res); // does some logic with the response
     }
```

Question : In short, i need a better a way to reuse this function for any method type/name listed out with just changing parameter is the Request.oml.

### Below is my solution to this problem, but need some better suggestions. Please ignore below if you find it lengthy

My Solution:

fill the method name in Request (method_name as enum - view/create/update/delete/update_all/delete_all).
Hence depending on the method name selected, i need to calculate url and  header.

```
    switch(req.get_method_name())
    {
    case add:
     // do something - calculate url
     break;
     case view :
     // do something - calculate url
     break;
     .....
     ....

    }
```

i wanted to repeat this same design for header, but depend upon method_type(get/post)

```
    switch(req.get_method_type())
    {
    case get:
    // prepare headers accordingly
    break;
    case post:
    // prepare headers accordingly
    break;
    ...
    }
```

Question : is there any way to achieve this? we need on keep on adding switch for the new operation..hence i'm looking for someother suggestion

Sorry for such a long query. let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: It would be nice if you could try to summarize your intend in the title sothat people know what it's about without necessarily read everything :-)

Comment: I really don't know why i get downvoted for asking suggestions..!! i just gave my question and solution and asked for a better suggestion,..!! but got bad response :(

Comment: Try posting on codereview.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: @MattMcNabb no. This question is not a good fit for codereview from what I see here. Sure the logic could be drastically improved, but as of now there's no guarantee that the code is actually working, and additionally it's not the real code of op (which would be a prerequisite for a codereview question). For more information, please read the codereview [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could make use of Command pattern here. refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern for more details.

The idea is that you create a Base class, Request (maybe), that exposes a method execute(), which you could call.

You could extend the Request base class and specialize on method type etc. All the complex code related to header formation and URL can be encapsulated twithin the specialized Request classes. So, that your execute_api() would look something like

```
execute_api() {
    ....
    ....
    Response& resp = request.execute(); //Generic for any request type
}
```

This pattern would ensure that your api dispatch request doesn't change with any new method type you add. You can extend this idea to Response class as well.

Hope it helps.

### Edit:

For request object creation, we could make use of [Simple Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) programming idiom. This is treated differently as compared to [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

So, the switch-cases would shift to this **SimpleRequestFactory**, thereby, localizing the code changes required for any future enhancements.

The above code might look something like below:

```
execute_api() {
....
Request& request = SimpleRequestFactory::getInstance()->createRequestObj();  // Singleton SimpleRequestFactory
Response& resp = request.execute(); //Generic for any request type
}
```

You could further improve it by introducing another level of abstraction (say), by creating AbstractRequestFactory class,  which can have sub-classes like PostRequestFactory, GetRequestFactory etc. So, execute_api might look something like below:

```
execute_api( AbstractRequestFactory& factory ) {
....
Request& request = factory.getRequestObject(/*pass req params*/);
Response& res = request.execute(); //Generic for any request type
}
```

Comment: Nice design ! But doesn't this require that the request object is created using the appropriate class ?  Wouldn't this be done with a switch also ?  And doesnt the GET/POST transformation follow the same logic whatever the request ist ?

Comment: @Christophe what if you passed the request object into `execute_api()` as a parameter?

Comment: @AtlasC1 I've understood that you now which method name (aka request class is needed) only in `fill_request_vo()` where the oml file is read...  But the snippet is ambiguous (because the const parameter doesn't match OP explanations).

Comment: @Christophe I think the object creation logic will have to use the switch-case to return the instantiated object. This can be encapsulated in a SimpleRequestFactory class. So, here, we've pushed the creation logic away from the actual request dispatch, and identified a single place for code modification if a need arises.